# Xamarin.Forms TimePicker Event does not work on viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, timepicker

I created a bindable property PropertyChangeCommandProperty that will call when I change the TimerPicer time PropertyChangeCommand did not call on viewmodel class.

Custom TimePicker with bindable property code:

```
public class BetterTimePicker : TimePicker
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty PropertyChangeCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PropertyChangeCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(BetterTimePicker), null);

        public ICommand PropertyChangeCommand {
            get => (ICommand)GetValue(PropertyChangeCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(PropertyChangeCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public BetterTimePicker()
        {
            this.PropertyChanged += BetterTimePicker_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void BetterTimePicker_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is TimePicker timePicker)
                PropertyChangeCommand?.Execute(timePicker);
        }
    }
```

Xaml Code:

```
<controls:BetterTimePicker PropertyChangeCommand="{Binding TimeChangedCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"
  Style="{StaticResource TimeStyle}"
Time="{Binding start_time, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

ViewModel Code:

```
public ICommand TimeChangedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((item) =>
            {

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it hit a breakpoint in the body of the `if` in your `BetterTimePicker_PropertyChanged` ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, BetterTimePicker_PropertyChanged is an event I want to call in ViewModel class

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the body of the 'if' in your `BetterTimePicker_PropertyChanged`, does the breakpoint get hit? Meaning, does the property changed event is properly fired ?

Comment: yes it's worked, but I want to get changed data in viewmodel class so my concern is how I get value in viewmodel class when PropertyChanged .

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?